# Trying to use POST request to PHP to retrieve database information in Android

Tags: php, android, http, post

I have an Android application linked to a Database. To access this database, I have PHP scripts that retrieve DB information as JSON, such as

```
<?php
$HOST = '127.0.0.1';
$PORT = "5432";
$DBNAME = "LOLRunes";
$USER = "postgres";
$PASSWORD = "sth";

$conn = pg_connect("host=$HOST port=$PORT dbname=$DBNAME user=$USER password=$PASSWORD");

if ($conn) {
    $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM champions");

    $data = array();

    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {            
        $data[] = $row;
    } //while

    pg_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($data);
} //if
?>
```

Then I try to make HTTP request to this PHP scripts from Android.

When I do GET requests everything works fine. Problem is, in some PHP scripts I need to do POST requests, mainly  for query parameters, e.g.:

```
<?php
$HOST = '127.0.0.1';
$PORT = "5432";
$DBNAME = "LOLRunes";
$USER = "postgres";
$PASSWORD = "sth";

$conn = pg_connect("host=$HOST port=$PORT dbname=$DBNAME user=$USER password=$PASSWORD");

if ($conn) {
    $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM runes_keystones WHERE path_id = " . $_POST["path_id"]);

    $data = array();

    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {            
        $data[] = $row;
    } //while

    pg_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($data);
} //if
?>
```

Now, if I access this php via a simple HTML web page with a form to send POST data, everything works fine and the result I get in browser is a JSON array.

But from Android Studio, the response I get is HTML code, something like:

```
 <br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: path_id in C:\wamp\www\getRunesKeystones.php on line <i>11</i></th></tr><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr><tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0003</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>248464</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\getRunesKeystones.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getRunesKeystones.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr></table></font><br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  error de sintaxis al final de la entradaLINE 1: SELECT * FROM runes_keystones WHERE path_id =                                                       ^ in C:\wamp\www\getRunesKeystones.php on line <i>11</i></th></tr><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr><tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0003</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>248464</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\getRunesKeystones.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getRunesKeystones.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0360</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>250720</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/pg_query' target='_new'>pg_query</a>(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\getRunesKeystones.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getRunesKeystones.php<b>:</b>11</td></tr></table></font><br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: pg_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\getRunesKeystones.php on line <i>15</i></th></tr><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr><tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0003</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>248464</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\getRunesKeystones.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getRunesKeystones.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0367</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>251144</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/pg_fetch_assoc' target='_new'>pg_fetch_assoc</a>(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\getRunesKeystones.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getRunesKeystones.php<b>:</b>15</td></tr></table></font>[]
```

when I would like to get a JSON array.

Code for POST request in Android:

```
 private JSONArray makePhpPostRequest(String phpUrl, String[][] postRequest) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JSONException {
    URL url = new URL(HOST_IP + phpUrl);

    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    //Build JSON containing POST args
    String requestJSON = "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < postRequest.length; i++) {
        String key = postRequest[i][0];
        String value = postRequest[i][1];

        requestJSON += "\"" + key + "\":\"" + value + "\"";

        if (i < postRequest.length - 1) {
            requestJSON += ",";
        } //if
    } //for
    requestJSON += "}";

    //Writing request JSON
    byte[] jsonByte = requestJSON.getBytes();
    OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(jsonByte, 0, jsonByte.length);

    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader((httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    String json = "";
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        json += inputLine;
    } //while

    Log.d("jsonResponse", json);

    bufferedReader.close();

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

    return jsonArray;
} //makePhpPostRequest
```

As you can see, I send POST parameters via a JSON I build from a String array. I already checked that request JSON is built properly:

```
{"path_id":"1"}
```

So I guess I'm doing something wrong with POST requests in Android. Any ideas?

Comment: Note; your PHP is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: How should I solve it? Is there a better way of concatenating POST into query?

Comment: No, there isn't a good way to concatenate it. Concatenation is insecure, you need to use Prepared Statements. This forces the data to be sent separately from the query itself to the MySQL server, so it eliminates the possibility of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing how I send POST data:

private JSONArray makePhpPostRequest(String phpUrl, String[][] postParameters) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JSONException {
        URL url = new URL(HOST_IP + phpUrl);

```
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    //Build URL parameters
    String urlParameters = "&";
    for (int i = 0; i < postParameters.length; i++) {
        String key = postParameters[i][0];
        String value = postParameters[i][1];

        urlParameters += key + "=" + value;
    } //for

    //Writing POST parameters
    OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(urlParameters);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader((httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    String json = "";
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        json += inputLine;
    } //while

    bufferedReader.close();

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

    return jsonArray;
} //makePhpPostRequest
```

Now I write those URL parameters instead of sending a JSON object